# Are there any examples where fractal geometry is applied in economics or finance?

Tags: mathematical-economics, finance

Can fractal geometry give better insights into the working of the financial markets or give rise to better financial models? If so, are there any existing models?

Answer (score 1):

Fractals applied to finance was a research area of Benoît Mandelbrot. He wrote books and research articles in the matter. Looking at his work could be a good way to start with.

Comment: +1. IIRC, not only fractals give better insights about finance (as the OP is asking), but finance was Mandelbrot's original motivation to develop fractals.